# Dataframe to excel file from a nested pattern

Tags: r

I am trying to make separate excel files with data from a nested data frame (with attributes specified in file name). How can I achieve this?

```
library(tidyverse)
nested<- mtcars %>%  group_by(vs, disp) %>% nest()
```

What do you think?

Comment: Do you have separate vector for file names

Comment: No, should i make one?

Comment: I thought to extract it from the group by vars

Comment: `mtcars %>%  group_by(gear) %>% nest() %>% group_walk(~writexl::write_xlsx(.x, paste0('/tmp/mtcars/gear-', .y$gear, '.xlsx')))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `iwalk` or `imap`

```
library(purrr)
library(openxlsx)
library(stringr)
imap(nested$data, ~ write.xlsx(.x, file = str_c('file', .y, '.xlsx')))
```

---

Or if we want to have the values of the groups as file name

```
pmap(nested, ~ write.xlsx(..3, 
          file = sprintf('file_%d_%d.xlsx', ..1, ..2)))
```

Comment: Thanks.. and if i add more nesting vars, just use 1.. 2.. 3.. 4... ?

Comment: @Stat.Enthus Yes, you can do that numbering in the order of occurrence

Comment: @akrun. I was using `dplyr::group_walk`, and getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. Used the purr method you shared above, it faired better but still get the java error. I think its the excel package issue. Is there any better package to write.xlsx

Comment: @user5249203 can you try with `write_xlsx` from `writexl` or `openxlsx::write.xlsx` Your package is not clear